# Using gps location system services dependency injection

Tags: c#, android, ios, mobile, xamarin

I am looking to get platform specific location details using Xamarin's dependency injection but running into issues. More than likely from doing it wrong.

Here is my current setup:

**nuMaps/Interfaces/ILocationService.cs**

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;

namespace nuMaps
{
    public interface ILocationService
    {
        void initLocationService();
        Position getCurrentPosition();
    }
}
```

**nuMaps/nuMaps.Droid/Interfaces/LocationService.cs**

```
using System;
using nuMaps;
using nuMaps.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using Android.App;
using Android.Gms.Common;
using Android.Gms.Common.Apis;
using Android.Gms.Location;
using Android.Locations;
using Android.Widget;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency (typeof (LocationService))]

namespace nuMaps.Droid
{
    public class LocationService : Java.Lang.Object, ILocationService, IGoogleApiClientConnectionCallbacks, IGoogleApiClientOnConnectionFailedListener, Android.Gms.Location.ILocationListener
    {
        readonly IGoogleApiClient _googleApiClient;
        readonly LocationRequest _locRequest;
        Position _currentPosition;
        Location _currentLocation;

        public LocationService()
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("LocationService constructor");
            _currentPosition = new Position (0, 0);

            _googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClientBuilder (Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context)
                .AddApi (LocationServices.Api)
                .AddConnectionCallbacks (this)
                .AddOnConnectionFailedListener (this)
                .Build ();

            _locRequest = new LocationRequest ();
        }

        #region ILocationService implementation

        public void initLocationService()
        {
            _googleApiClient.Connect ();
        }

        public Position getCurrentPosition ()
        {
            if (_googleApiClient.IsConnected) {
                _currentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.GetLastLocation (_googleApiClient);
                _currentPosition = new Position (_currentLocation.Latitude, _currentLocation.Longitude);
            }

            _googleApiClient.Disconnect ();

            return new Position (_currentLocation.Latitude, _currentLocation.Longitude);
        }

        #endregion
        public void OnLocationChanged(Location l)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("OnLocationChanged");
            _currentLocation = l;
        }

        public void OnConnectionFailed (ConnectionResult result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("ConnectionFailed");
        }

        #region IGoogleApiClientConnectionCallbacks implementation
        public void OnConnected (Android.OS.Bundle connectionHint)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("OnConnected");

            if (!_googleApiClient.IsConnected)
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.RequestLocationUpdates (_googleApiClient, _locRequest, this);

            _currentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.GetLastLocation (_googleApiClient);
        }
        public void OnConnectionSuspended (int cause)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("OnConnectionSuspended");
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

**Usage in nuMaps/Views/MapPage.xaml.cs**

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace nuMaps
{
    public partial class MapPage : ContentPage
    {

        public MapPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            Position p = DependencyService.Get<ILocationService>().getCurrentPosition();
            MyMap.MoveToRegion (
                MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius (
                    p, Distance.FromMiles (1)
                )
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**nuMaps/Views/Loginpage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using nuMaps;

namespace nuMaps
{
    public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
    {
        public LoginPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();

            /*
             * Init platform specific location service.
             * TODO: This *shouldn't* need to happen, but we don't get location information until
             * the OnConnected callback happens which is too slow to put in getCurrentLocation method.
             */

             DependencyService.Get<ILocationService>().initLocationService();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: GetSystemService (Context.LocationService) returns a reference to LocationManager - why are you trying to Writeline it?  You use that object to request GPS updates.  Read this for more: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/location/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is in your implementation of `ILocationService`.

I would remove implementing activity (why do you want to use OnCreate?) and take a look at http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/location/.

I'd recommend on Android getting the GPS location via the google play apis, which will require implementing `ILocationListener`, `IGoogleApiClientConnectionCallbacks`, and `IGoogleApiClientOnConnectionFailedListener`. Hope that helps!

Edit for comments:

If the LocationService in the question is up to date, I don't see that you're implementing `IGoogleApiClientConnectionCallbacks` or `ILocationListener`. It may be that because the mappage is using gps, `GetLastKnownLocation` works, because a location has recently been obtained.

GPS location requesting is an async operation - one of the methods with `IGoogleApiClientConnectionCallbacks` is OnConnected, where you should call something like:

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.RequestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
```

This will actively request location updates, and then fire `OnLocationChanged(Location location)` when an location update is returned. This is all async, so you'll likely need to expose these events in your LocationService and subscribe to them.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply! I tested implementing those interfaces instead and I seem to have the same issue as just implementing my ILocationServer. They never seem to trigger. My ILocationService::getCurrentPosition is called, but doesn't have the proper contexts to get the device's current location.

Comment: Hmm, have you tried using Forms.Context as the context?

Comment: I did have some luck changing the context.. of Context to Application.Context and removing the Activity implementation. The only problem that remains is how to properly get Location when the View/Map is first loaded or any other time during the application lifecycle before the map is viewed.

Comment: Glad you got part of it working! You should be able to call that service at any time in the app lifecycle, as the google play location service is not tied to a map control (unless I'm misunderstanding your issue).

Comment: Calling getCurrentLocation in MapPage.xaml.cs seems to result in a null location. I also tried using the override OnAppearing(), but that was null as well.

Comment: Just updated my answer with some new info, let me know if that helps

Comment: Your updates put me in the right direction. I still had my main problem of Location not being available without OnLocationChanged firing first. My work around was to "init" the service on app startup so it's ready to go when the MapPage is loaded. **Also**, I was testing this on an emulator. It seems that GetLastKnownLocation is more readily available/reliable on actual device. So the current solution **may** be overkill. Any thoughts?

Comment: That makes sense - I think doing an 'init' of the service on app startup is an acceptable solution - maybe you could check getlastknownlocation at startup to see if it's necessary, and only init then? Like you said, users with actual devices will most likely have a last known location so it probably won't be an issue. I'd advise doing most testing on a device if you can in order to suss out any GPS oddities that may occur. Glad it's working though! Don't forget to mark the answer too.

Comment: @DonBoots Hi , m using fusedlocationApi in xamarin to get the current location , but m stuck in getting current location. I have created dependency service and use that to initialize location service on app startup(app.xaml.cs) , problem with this is that apiclient never connects. and if I initialize service on some other page other than app.xaml.cs , it connects but it does not fire locationchanged() ,thus not getting current location.Any solution? m stuck here for past 1 week

Answer (score 0):

You could give [TinyIoC](https://github.com/grumpydev/TinyIoC) a try instead of the Xamarin Dependency Service. It works well for platform-specific implementations, like location services.

Maybe the Xamarin Dependency Service can be used for these types of things, but I've only used it for custom Renderers so far. For more service-based stuff, I use TinyIoC.